# Unix Command to list Few Latest Files

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I use below UNIX command to list files in order of their creation/modification. But as the directory has hundreds of files, it take few seconds to list down. but I don't want all age old files to be listed.

```
ls -ltr
```

Please provide the command for below situations.

1. List files generated/created in last 24 hours.
2. List down 50 latest files

Please help me with Unix commands for above 2 cases.

Comment: `head` solves the second problem.

Comment: You could use `find` or pipe your `ls` through `head` or `tail`

Comment: @John3136, +1 can you please give me unix command ? I will try running it directly. will also give u reputation.

Comment: Unix does not track the creation time of the file.  The best you can do is track the last time the file was modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50 latest files:

```
ls -ltr | tail -50
```

or

```
ls -lt | head -50
```

Edit:
Files modified in last day

```
find . -mtime -1
```

You could also try

```
ls -lt `find . -mtime -1` | head -50
```

But there is a problem... if `find . -mtime -1` would return nothing (no file was modified in last day) you will get the last 50 files of all the time %\

Comment: +1 Wow. This command works !

Comment: how to get command run in last 1 day ?

Comment: This was a suggestion of all guys who had already answered to you.

Comment: find .mtime -1 is good, but I couldn't see time,permissions that I see for ls -lrt :)

Comment: @UmeshPatil: If you could *eventually* be bothered to *look up* `man find`, you will find that you are completely at liberty to get any kind of output in any kind of format you could ever wish for via the `-printf` option.

Comment: @DevSolar, thanks. I don't like the format of Unix Manual. They don't provide examples

Answer (score 2):

> 1. List files generated/created in last 24 hours.

Use find newer or mtime parameters:

```
find . -newer
find . -mtime -50
```

> 1. List down 50 latest files

Pipe through head or tail depending on the sort order you used

Comment: can you please also provide command with pipe ?

Comment: find . -newer is not working.

Comment: @UmeshPatil: ...because it needs a reference. *Do* try the manual (`man find`).

Comment: okay. Thanks DevSolar. I could at least get example command.